# MODX Revo custom sort order for getCollection

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I have an array with id's:

```
$ids = array(240, 12, 400);
```

And I want to get those objects in that order with `$modx->getCollection('modResource');`

How can I accomplish that?

if I do like this:

```
$res = $modx->getCollection('modResource', array(
    'id:IN' => $ids
));
```

the boxes are in ASC order, but I want them in this order: 240, 12 400...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$criteria = $modx->newQuery('modResource');
$criteria->sortby('FIELD(modResource.id, '.implode(',',$ids).' )', 'DESC');
$criteria->where(array(
    'id:IN' => $ids
));
$res = $modx->getCollection('modResource', $criteria);
```

Comment: That hit the spot! I had to change DESC to ASC in my example, but hey, its all good!